# Magento 2.2 Rest Api creating same url-key for different product names

Tags: magento2.2.2

has anyone already faced the problem in Magento 2.2, that you have two different product names and magento creates the same url-key for both? Like:

name: Product Name 1 url-key: product-name-1

name: Product Name 2 url-key: product-name-1

I´m having this problem right now. I´m posting two different products with different product names and magento is just adding one product to the store and I wondered why. So I had a look at my posted content and the response from magento. And magento is using the url-key from product 1 for product 2, even though I have two separate posts to the api for these two products. Can´t explain why magento is doing this and I haven´t found any solution to it or problem/bug for Magento 2.2, but implement and post my own url-key. I also deleted the url-keys in url_rewrite database.

I´ve already added lots of products in same kind of post without any problem.

Comment: I can add now, that I have in Backend Catalog -> products in overview of the products the product 2 shown. When I click on it, it opens product 1 to edit.
But product 2 is in frontend in the categories.

Comment: If someone faces the same problem:
If you post products with same sku it just overrides the first product with the new information. Right way for magento API would be, that it errors with "sku is already in use".
In that case you "update" the product, which should only be possible through "put" not through "post".
Don´t know if there is any logic behind updating through "post" - there is no for me.